# Changing the first argument of l@chapter

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, chapters

In the table of contents, I want the chapters to appear like

> Chapter 1: Preface

and

> Chapter 4: Advanced Topics

I tried to modify the `\l@chapter` command as shown in the MWE but what I get is actually

> Chapter 1 Preface:

How to fix it?

*I want to do it without `titletoc` or `tocloft`.*

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@chapter[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \vskip 1.0em \@plus\p@
    \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode \bfseries
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
      \hskip -\leftskip
      Chapter #1:\nobreak\hfil % <<<--- Changed
      \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2%
                                 \kern-\p@\kern\p@}\par
      \penalty\@highpenalty
    \endgroup
  \fi}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Preface}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The chapter number is printed in the `\@chapter` command, not in the `\l@chapter` command.  So you need to patch both commands to do what you want without using one of the TOC packages:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\l@chapter}{#1}{\chaptername{} #1}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@chapter}{\numberline{\thechapter}}{\numberline{\thechapter:}}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Preface}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]